# Apps on SD-Card moved back to device storage after being updated?

Tags: google-play-store, 5.0-lollipop, app2sd, samsung-galaxy-s-5

On my Samsung Galaxy S5 (running Lollipop 5.0), I noticed the following behavior:

- I moved some apps to my external SD-Card storage.
- Every time, Google Play Store tells me to update one of these apps, they're getting moved back to the device's storage - and I have to push them back again to the SD-Card.

Did anyone encounter the same issue (or is this maybe just my phone)? This behavior does not show up on my old Galaxy (Android 4.1.2 - apps keep their place there, even after being updated).

Since I think, that it's very annoying to check whether apps should be moved to the SD-Card again, can somebody please tell me, how to stop this behavior or automate app2sd for specific apps?

**Edit**: I did not root my phone

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, have you found a solution?

Comment: @mariosangiorgio Unfortunately, not. I got used to use some apps, that notify me about updated apps and then I have to move them manually :(

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you don't have you SD card selected as the default installation location. Which makes the app install back onto the internal storage.

To fix this got to `Settings > Storage > Preferred install location` then select SD card. After you update it will install app on the SD card by default.

Comment: where can I find these settings? PlayStore or Android settings? I could not find it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: They where an android settings try searching the app

Comment: Screen shot please! of your android settings. There must be a `Storage` option, inside which you have `Storage Settings`. There you can change the default storage to External Storage or SD card.

Comment: I can't find this setting anywhere...

Comment: This setting simply does not exist on my (stock) LG G5 running Android 7.0. Naturally, Google has no problem defaulting to shoving all my apps back on internal storage despite lack of a setting for that (or space to do so).